# Múltipla Renderização Livewire

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando realizar duas renderizações no livewire, porém so a primeira renderiza e a segunda copia a primeira. Se eu mudo a ordem a regra se aplica.

`

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <livewire:produto.microorganismos-adicionar :microorganismos_id="$microorganismos_id" :produto_id="$produto_id"/>
  <div class=" clearfix mt-4">
    <section id="steps-uid-0-p-2" aria-labelledby="steps-uid-0-h-2" class="body" aria-hidden="true">
      <livewire:produto.microorganismos-selecionados :microorganismos_id="$microorganismos_id" :produto_id="$produto_id"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <livewire:produto.fisico-quimicos-adicionar :fisico_quimicos_id="$fisico_quimicos_id" :produto_id="$produto_id"/>

  <div class=" clearfix mt-4">
    <section id="steps-uid-1-p-2" aria-labelledby="steps-uid-0-h-2" class="body" aria-hidden="true">
      <livewire:produto.fisico-quimicos-selecionados :fisico_quimicos_id="$fisico_quimicos_id" :produto_id="$produto_id"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

O que parece é que a renderização não acontece por questão de ordem, mas não consegui encontrar nada que me faça manipular isso.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que adicionando `:wire:key="$produto_id"` te ajude.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components#keyed-components